# Extract Badge ID from JSON in .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: json, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I've got an [exampleproject](https://gitlab.com/mstein/badge_number_example_repo) at gitlab where I would like to get the ID of the last badge in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` via script. I get the overview of all badges [as a json](https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/12412978/badges). Is there a way to get the "id" of the last element?

At the moment I'm setting a custom CI variable `PYLINT_BADGE_ID` by hand from the [json](https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/12412978/badges) for each project. In this case it is 37777. How to automate this by commandline?

## Details:

I'm trying to solve this question: [Pylint badge in gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126475/pylintbadge-in-gitlab). But they use gitlab pages, anybadge, artifacts and the readme to display badges (which is not in the standard badge area). The following way feels more slim:

[This is the .gitlab-ci.yml I'm using](https://gitlab.com/mstein/badge_number_example_repo/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml)

```
lint:
  script:
  - python -m pip install setuptools
  - python -m pip install pylint pylint-exit
  - pylint src/*.py | tee pylint.txt || pylint-exit $?
  - score=$(sed -n 's/^Your code has been rated at \([-0-9.]*\)\/.*/\1/p' pylint.txt)
  - echo "Pylint score was $score"
  # To check your badge ID go to https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/43126475/badges
  # and insert your $CI_PROJECT_ID. Must be a quite high number!
  # Would be great to automate this!
  - badge_url=https://img.shields.io/badge/lint%20score-$score-blue.svg
  - >-
        curl https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/badges/$PYLINT_BADGE_ID
        -X PUT
        -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $API_TOKEN"
        -H "Content-Type: application/json"
        -d '{"image_url": "'"$badge_url"'"}'

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - pylint.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

After some hours of regex escaping I added this to my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
  - json_badge_info=$(curl -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN:$API_TOKEN" -X GET https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/badges)
  - pylint_badge_id=$(expr match "$json_badge_info" '.*https[^"]*-blue\.svg\",\"id\":\([0-9]\+\),')
```

So the whole stage looks like this:

```
lint:
  stage: unittest-lint

  script:
  - python -m pip install setuptools pylint pylint-exit
  - pylint src/*.py | tee pylint.txt || pylint-exit $?
  - score=$(sed -n 's/^Your code has been rated at \([-0-9.]*\)\/.*/\1/p' pylint.txt)
  - echo "Pylint score was $score"

  # get the json with all badge urls via API and regex the id of the badge with 'blue.svg' in it
  - json_badge_info=$(curl -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN:$API_TOKEN" -X GET https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/badges)
  - pylint_badge_id=$(expr match "$json_badge_info" '.*https[^"]*-blue\.svg\",\"id\":\([0-9]\+\),')
  - echo $pylint_badge_id

  - badge_url=https://img.shields.io/badge/lint%20score-$score-blue.svg
  - >-
        curl https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/badges/$pylint_badge_id
        -X PUT
        -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $API_TOKEN"
        -H "Content-Type: application/json"
        -d '{"image_url": "'"$badge_url"'"}'

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - pylint.txt
```

This solution depends on the order of the elements in the regex looks for `-blue.svg` in the json, which needs to be before the badge id.